# pass data flutter/dart get method

Tags: flutter, http, dart

On the new version of the dart http module for flutter I have a problem
indeed I want to use an API with the get method by passing arguments

```
'http://host.com?data1=1&data2=2' ...
```

And since the new version we have to put the url this way

```
http.get(
   Uri.http ('host.com', '/'),
)
```

or I don't know how to pass the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put it in the form

```
Uri.http ('host.com', '/',parameters),
```

Inside parameters you have to put a Map like

```
Map<String, String> parameters = { "data1" : "1" }
```

And if you are using http dont forget to put

```
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/>
```

inside your AndroidManifest.xml because otherwise you get the next error :) .

Answer (score 2):

Use the query parameters parameter of the [`Uri.http`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html) constructor.

```
Uri.http ('host.com', '/', {
  'data1': '1',
  'data2': '2',
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For url parameters, you can try just:

```
String url = 'http://host.com';
url += '?data1=1';

var response = await http.get(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap your old url String with [Uri.parse](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-core/Uri/parse.html).

```
http.get(Uri.parse('http://host.com?data1=1&data2=2'));
```